# should i publish separate apk for each region or localize a single apk for each region?

Tags: android, google-play, app-store, mobile-application

We have built a mobile platform that has 95% of the functionality same but there are a few things that we have localized for each region (EU, US/Canada, Middle East, and South Asia). For performance and data policy reasons, we have also separated the backends for each region.

Now when publishing to Appstore, we have two options.

1. Publish a separate version to each region.
2. Publish a single version but localize it based on the phone number/location of the user. At the launch of the app, based on the phone number that user enters, he will be redirected to the data region that belongs to the phone number or region of the users.

Especially due to GDPR, we don't want the EU data to be visible to users from other countries and there are few other options that are different for EU users.

Can someone please guide whether a separate app would make sense or a single version with conditions based on the user's region would be enough? What could be the pro and cons of both options?

Regards
Syed

Comment: "phone number/location of the user" is not a reliable way to choose the region. VPNs and rented phone numbers are common today.

Comment: so do you suggest that a separate app for each region is the way to go?